# React Native State not updating with an empty Array

Tags: javascript, react-native, state

Hi stackoverflow people I know this has been asked about a million times. However I don't think I have found an answer to my problem!

Long story short I am updating a state in my react native app only if a statement is true. What I am experiencing is this state not being updated somehow.

```
const emptyArray = []
const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(true);
const [selectedGem, setSelectedGem] = useState(false);
const [usedGem, setUsedGem] = useState(emptyArray);
const [selectedPropType, setSelectedPropType] = useState('all');

const randomItem = (items) => {
    return items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
}

const getRandomQuestion = () => {
    let selectableGems = gems

    const maxGems = selectableGems.length;
    let tempGems = [];

    if(usedGem.length >= maxGems) {
        setUsedGem(emptyArray)
    }

    for (let i=0; i<maxGems; i++)
    {
        if(usedGem.length === 0 || usedGem.find(gem => gem === i) === undefined) {
            tempGems.push(i)
        }
    }

    const randomGemNumber = randomItem(tempGems)

    setUsedGem([...usedGem, randomGemNumber])

    setSelectedGem(selectableGems[randomGemNumber])
}
```

Basically `if(usedGem.length >= maxGems) {`happens only when all the gems have been randomised once (there are 130 item in the `gems` variable). I'd expect then the `usedGem` to be empty in the `for` but this isn't the case.

I have tried a few solutions I found without luck. I know this has to do with async but I can't figure it out! Anyone could help me please?

Comment: Setting state in React is not "instantaneous". You will see the new state only on the next render.

Comment: Are you sure the statement if(usedGem.length >= maxGems) is true? Try console.log the length before hand and maybe put a console log inside the IF to confirm it does go inside the IF statement to execute.  

Or as @tromgy mentioned above - more likely.

Comment: Yeah I had a console.log there to prove my self it was true. Perhaps @tromgy is right , I need to wait the next render

Answer (score 0):

Here this might help. The thing is you can't get instant update after setting state

```
const getRandomQuestion = () => {
let selectableGems = gems

const maxGems = selectableGems.length;
let tempGems = [];
let gems = Array.from(usedGem);

if(gems.length >= maxGems) {
    gems = []
}

for (let i=0; i<maxGems; i++)
{
    if(gems.length === 0 || gems.find(gem => gem === i) === undefined) {
        tempGems.push(i)
    }
}

const randomGemNumber = randomItem(tempGems)

setUsedGem([...gems, randomGemNumber])

setSelectedGem(selectableGems[randomGemNumber])
}
```